# Does the weapon effect "extra damage against elites" also apply to bosses?

Tags: diablo-iii

I just got a weapon that has the following attribute: "4% extra damage against elites".

Does this also apply when I am fighting bosses?

Answer (score 5):

> Elite monsters are any monster which have special attributes not normally found on their base type. Champions, Rares, and also Superunique monsters are all considered "elite".

Source: http://www.diablowiki.net/Elite

Answer (score 0):

Well according to the diablo wiki (not sure how "respected" this is) .

A [Monster](http://www.diablowiki.net/Monster)

```
Elite: Tough. Stronger attacks. Or both.
```

"Designed to make the player pause and think. High damage attack, high hit points, etc. Something different. Scary and dangerous, more so than the lieutenant. "

And [bosses](http://www.diablowiki.net/Bosses)

Bosses (technically known as "SuperUniques") are specially named and located enemies who may have different, unique graphics and special story importance.

This would imply that a boss counts as an elite.